# How to get over 30FPS using Java in a Screen Capture Program?

Tags: java, screen, capture, recording, awtrobot

I'm currently using the Robot classes in Java to record the screen. However, it does not achieve the minimum of 30 frames per second. I'm not re-creating objects, and am being as efficient as I can, but I only average around 15 frames per second. Robot is simply not cutting it.

What can I use to capture the screen? I've tried Xuggle, but I can't seem to get that to capture fast enough either.

Comment: FFmpeg supports [x11grab video input](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#x11grab) that works fast, but only for the X Window System. If that is satisfactory, the `FFmpegFrameGrabber` class of [JavaCV](http://code.google.com/p/javacv/) can get you the images. Let me know if you want some sample code as answer

Comment: Yeah, it might help for it. I'm not sure how I'd do that...

Comment: I wanted to say, do you care about Windows and Mac OS X, for example, or is X11 sufficient?

Comment: I'd like it be windows, if you know how to exactly.
Could you also show me the X11 method as well?

Comment: Robot is probably too slow for that unless it's been reimplemented in the latest JDK.

Comment: Yes, hence why I'm waiting for Samual Audet's method.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For operating systems following the X11 standard (Linux, FreeBSD, Solaris, etc.), we can do it this way via [JavaCV](http://code.google.com/p/javacv/) and [FFmpeg](http://ffmpeg.org/):

```
import com.googlecode.javacv.*;

public class ScreenGrabber {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        int x = 0, y = 0, w = 1024, h = 768; // specify the region of screen to grab
        FFmpegFrameGrabber grabber = new FFmpegFrameGrabber(":0.0+" + x + "," + y);
        grabber.setFormat("x11grab");
        grabber.setImageWidth(w);
        grabber.setImageHeight(h);
        grabber.start();

        CanvasFrame frame = new CanvasFrame("Screen Capture");
        while (frame.isVisible()) {
            frame.showImage(grabber.grab());
        }
        frame.dispose();
        grabber.stop();
    }
}
```

I don't know about Windows or Mac OS X, but I suspect we would need to access native APIs directly. Nevertheless, [JavaCPP](http://code.google.com/p/javacpp/) could help with that.

Comment: According to https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Capture/Desktop you should be able to use the same API just using a different `device` (`dshow` instead of `x11grab` for Windows and `avfoundation` for OSX)

Answer (score 5):

Build on @Samuel's answer, according to the official [ffmpeg documentation](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Capture/Desktop) you should be able to keep it pretty cross platform if you make the `file` parameter passed to the `FFmpegFrameGrabber` (which is really an `input` parameter that gets passed down as the `-i` option to ffmpeg) adhere to the [different formats each `device` expects](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-devices.html).

ie:

for Windows: `dshow` expects `-i video="screen-capture-recorder"`

for OSX: `avfoundation` expects `-i "<screen device index>:"`

and for Linux: `x11grab` expects `-i :<display id>+<x>,<y>`.

So just passing those values (arguments to `-i`) to the constructor and setting the format (via `setFormat`) accordingly should do the trick:

Examples:

for Windows:

```
new FFmpegFrameGrabber("video=\"screen-capture-recorder\"")
    .setFormat("dshow");
```

for OSX:

```
new FFmpegFrameGrabber("\"<screen device index>:\"")
    .setFormat("avfoundation");
```

for Linux:

```
new FFmpegFrameGrabber(":<display id>+<x>,<y>")
    .setFormat("x11grab");
```

PS: Haven't tested this fully so not sure if the quotes are actually necessary.

Comment: can you elaborate on how to set the options for windows a bit more? I'm trying to find out which options need to go into the format and which go into the constructor. Thank you.

Comment: Edited my answer and added a few examples showing the parameters being passed.

Comment: For Windows specifically you could also use `gdigrab` as a format and pass the input/file parameter and options accordingly. See http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-devices.html for more.

Comment: I'm getting the following error:
org.bytedeco.javacv.FrameGrabber$Exception: avformat_open_input() error -5: Could not open input "video='screen-capture-recorder'". (Has setFormat() been called?). I'm using the following code: 
        FFmpegFrameGrabber retVal = new FFmpegFrameGrabber("video='screen-capture-recorder'");
        retVal.setFormat("gdigrab"); The error occurs when I call the start method of the return object.

Comment: the `video=screen-capture-recorder` is the parameter the `dshow` device/format expects. if you're going to use `gdigrab` you will need to pass the corresponding format. Check the page I linked to for more.