# issues in recording screen using java applet "Jcapture"

Tags: java, applet, screen-recording

I found an applet 'jcapture' for recording screen, but the quality of the video saved is not upto the mark.Is there any other such app which I can use?

Comment: *"the video saved is not upto the mark"*  What is 'the mark'?

Comment: I mean to say its quality is not good.

Comment: See the [Monte Media Library](http://www.randelshofer.ch/monte/) as discussed in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20297514/418556).