# Fast screen capture Java

Tags: java, performance, screen, capture

I'm trying to create Ambilight using some LED strips connected to a Raspberry Pi running Raspbian. I'm building an application with Java which has to read out the colors of the pixels on all sides of the screen so I can use those to color the LEDs behind the screen.

I've tried making screenshots with `robot.createScreenCapture()` but it takes +- 45ms to run that line which causes the LEDs to change color way too late.

Does anyone have an idea of how to create a screenshot faster or how to get the pixel colors another way which reduces the ms?

This is the method I currently use to get a screenshot:

```
Robot robot = new Robot();
Rectangle area = new Rectangle(0, 0, this.screenSize.width, this.screenSize.height);
BufferedImage bufferedImage = robot.createScreenCapture(area); //Slow line
```

Comment: @WeareBorg robot class. `java.awt.Robot`

Comment: you only need to run `robot.createScreenCapture(area);` if you run this in a loop

Comment: Seriously, I thought it was Robot's child as robot. I am asking from which framework it is. Or if it's your own implementation, then show code for createScreenCapture

Comment: @WeareBorg `createScreenCapture()` is a built in method of robot class

Comment: @MartinDrost are you running this code in a loop ?

Comment: @FastSnail no, I'm making a screenshot once and I'm using that image to get the pixel data. The problem is that just the `createScreenCapture()` method takes +-45ms

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17665529/faster-alternative-to-java-awt-robot-createscreencapture

Comment: "+- 45ms to run that line which causes the LEDs to change color way too late" - that might change the color of the led ~22 times per second. Sounds stressfull to me.

Answer (score -1):

Use method getPixelColor() on robot

Comment: I've tried that but it has only proven to be slower than `createScreenCapture()` since I have to get the pixel colors of a lot of pixels